# Reverse an array without using a loop in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm

I have a coding challenge to reverse a an array with 5 elements in it. How would I do this without using the reverse method?

Code:

```
def reverse(array)
 array
end

p reverse(["a", 1, "apple", 8, 90])
```

Comment: array.values_at( 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 )

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please? In the question text you ask about reversing without using `Array#reverse`, but in the question title you are asking about reversing without using a loop (and yet you accepted an answer which uses a loop).

Comment: If we have a collection, we need to loop or iterate. No escape.

Comment: So what do StackOverflow get for answering your coding challenge for you?! :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can treat array as a stack and `pop` the elements from the end:

```
def reverse(array)
  rev = []
  rev << array.pop until array.empty?
  rev
end
```

or if you don't like modifying objects, use more functional-like `reduce`:

```
def reverse(array)
  array.reduce([]) {|acc, x| [x] + acc}
end
```

Cary mentioned in the comment about the performance. The functional approach might not be the fastest way, so if you really want to do it fast, create a buffor array and just add the items from the end to begin:

```
def reverse(array)
  reversed = Array.new(array.count)
  array.each_with_index do |item, index|
    reversed[-(index + 1)] = item
  end
  reversed
end
```

Comment: The latter has the efficiency disadvantage of creating a new array for each `x`.  If you look at `acc.object_id` you'll see it changes each iteration.

Comment: Yes, of course - this is a pure functional approach, without modifying any data, so the new object must be created every iteration.

Answer (score 4):

**Gentlemen, start your engines!**

**[Edit:** added two method from @Grych and results for n = 8_000.]

@Grych, @ArupRakshit, @konsolebox and @JörgWMittag: please check that I've written your method(s) correctly.

**Methods**

```
def grych_reduce(array)
  array.reduce([]) {|acc, x| [x] + acc}
end

def grych_prebuild(array)
  reversed = Array.new(array.count)
  array.each_with_index do |item, index|
    reversed[-(index + 1)] = item
  end
  reversed
end

def arup(ary)
  ary.values_at(*(ary.size-1).downto(0))
end

def konsolebox(array)
  t = array.pop
  konsolebox(array) if array.length > 0
  array.unshift t
end    

def jorg_recurse(array)
  return array if array.size < 2
  reverse(array.drop(1)) + array.first(1)
end

def jorg_tail(array, accum=[])
  return accum if array.empty?
  reverse(array.drop(1), array.first(1) + accum)
end

def jorg_fold(array)
  array.reduce([]) {|accum, el| [el] + accum }
end

def jorg_loop(array)
  array.each_with_object([]) {|el, accum| accum.unshift(el) }
end

def cary_rotate(arr)
  arr.size.times.with_object([]) { |_,a| a << arr.rotate!(-1).first }
end

def cary_boring(arr)
  (arr.size-1).downto(0).with_object([]) { |i,a| a << arr[i] }
end
```

**Benchmark**

```
require 'benchmark'

arr = [*(1..n)]
puts "n = #{n}"    

Benchmark.bm(16) do |bm|
  bm.report('grych_reduce')    { grych_reduce(arr) }
  bm.report('grych_prebuild')  { grych_prebuild(arr) }
  bm.report('arup')            { arup(arr)  }
  bm.report('konsolebox')      { konsolebox(arr) }
  bm.report('jorg_recurse')    { jorg_recurse(arr) }
  bm.report('jorg_tail')       { jorg_tail(arr)  }
  bm.report('jorg_fold')       { jorg_fold(arr)  }
  bm.report('jorg_loop')       { jorg_loop(arr)  }
  bm.report('cary_rotate')     { cary_rotate(arr)  }
  bm.report('cary_boring')     { cary_boring(arr) }
  bm.report('grych_destructo') { grych_destructo(arr) }
end
```

**Wednesday: warm-up (n = 8_000)**

```
                       user     system      total        real
grych_reduce       0.060000   0.060000   0.120000 (  0.115510)
grych_prebuild     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001150)
arup               0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000563)
konsolebox         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001581)
jorg_recurse       0.060000   0.040000   0.100000 (  0.096417)
jorg_tail          0.210000   0.070000   0.280000 (  0.282729)
jorg_fold          0.060000   0.080000   0.140000 (  0.138216)
jorg_loop          0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001174)
cary_rotate        0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.056863)
cary_boring        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000961)
grych_destructo    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000524)
```

**Thursday: trials #1 (n = 10_000)**

```
                       user     system      total        real
grych_reduce       0.090000   0.080000   0.170000 (  0.163276)
grych_prebuild     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001500)
arup               0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000706)
jorg_fold          0.080000   0.060000   0.140000 (  0.139656)
jorg_loop          0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001388)
cary_rotate        0.090000   0.000000   0.090000 (  0.087327)
cary_boring        0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001185)
grych_destructo    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000694)
```

`konsolebox`, `jorg_recurse` and `jorg_tail` eliminated (stack level too deep).

**Friday: trials #2 (n = 50_000)**

```
                       user     system      total        real
grych_reduce       2.430000   3.490000   5.920000 (  5.920393)
grych_prebuild     0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.007000)
arup               0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003826)
jorg_fold          2.430000   3.590000   6.020000 (  6.026433)
jorg_loop          0.010000   0.010000   0.020000 (  0.008491)
cary_rotate        2.680000   0.000000   2.680000 (  2.686009)
cary_boring        0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.006122)
grych_destructo    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003288)
```

**Saturday: qualifications (n = 200_000)**

```
                       user     system      total        real
grych_reduce      43.720000  66.140000 109.860000 (109.901040)
grych_prebuild     0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.028287)
jorg_fold         43.700000  66.490000 110.190000 (110.252620)
jorg_loop          0.030000   0.010000   0.040000 (  0.030409)
cary_rotate       43.060000   0.050000  43.110000 ( 43.118151)
cary_boring        0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.024570)
grych_destructo    0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.013338)
```

`arup_verse` eliminated (stack level too deep); `grych_reduce`, `jorg_fold` and `cary_rotate` eliminated (uncompetitive).

**Sunday: final (n = 10_000_000)**

```
                       user     system      total        real
grych_prebuild     1.450000   0.020000   1.470000 (  1.478903)
jorg_loop          1.530000   0.040000   1.570000 (  1.649403)
cary_boring        1.250000   0.040000   1.290000 (  1.288357)
grych_destructo    0.640000   0.030000   0.670000 (  0.689819)
```

Comment: You hurt me at last! :-)

Comment: One thing.. I learned today.. There is a _limit_ to the number arguments of a method.

Comment: This is a great benchmark, thanks! Could you please add the method I just added to my answer (the one with `each_with_index`)? It should be quite fast I assume

Comment: Yeah I expected it nevertheless recursion is the only method you can have if you don't want to use a loop :)

Answer (score 3):

Recursion indeed is the solution if you're not going to use a loop. `while` or `until` is still a loop, and using built-in methods not doing recursion may also still be using a loop internally.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

a = [1, 2, 3]

def reverse(array)
  t = array.pop
  reverse(array) if array.length > 0
  array.unshift t
end

puts reverse(Array.new(a)).inspect # [3, 2, 1]
```

#### Update

Naturally recursion has limits since it depends on the stack but that's the best you can have if you don't want to use a loop. Following [Cary Swoveland's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25102124/445221), this is the benchmark on **8500** elements:

```
                         user     system      total        real
@Grych               0.060000   0.010000   0.070000 (  0.073179)
@ArupRakshit         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000836)
@konsolebox          0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001771)
@JörgWMittag recursion  0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.053475)
@Jörg        tail    0.210000   0.040000   0.250000 (  0.246849)
@Jörg        fold    0.040000   0.010000   0.050000 (  0.045788)
@Jörg        loop    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000924)
Cary         rotate  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.059954)
Cary         boring  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.001004)
```

Comment: You can have a different implementation. But you shouldn't *override* core methods.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Originally yes, but I thought I wouldn't want to define a method that doesn't explicitly say that it alters its argument's data.

Comment: An obvious way is to create a new array instance within but that would complicate the recursion method with `if`s. Another obvious method as well is to use a submethod like `__reverse`.

Answer (score 2):

One thought :-

```
ary = ["a", 1, "apple", 8, 90]
ary.values_at(*(ary.size-1).downto(0))
# => [90, 8, "apple", 1, "a"]
```

`ary.size.downto(0)` gives `#<Enumerator: ...>`. And `*#<Enumerator: ...>` is just a [`Enumerable#to_a`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a) method call which *splats* the `Enumerator` to `[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]`. Finally, `Array#values_at` is working as [documented](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-values_at).

Comment: Arup, is there a way to count downwards with the infamous `for` loop?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky When you use `for` loop, it also call internally `#each` method. So you can't do with `for` loop.

Comment: I'd be thinking more about something like `for x in [*4..0] do ... end`, but that doesn't work. So I just wondered whether the infamous `for` loop can actually count downwards.

Comment: That means the only way to perform something similar would be by using `while` / `until` loop and decrement by hand...

Comment: yes.. But why don't you like `Fixnum#downto` method ? :-)

Comment: Don't be mistaken, I like it, especially considering I nearly forgot it :-) But I was just curious whether `for` loop with all its shortcomings actually can count downwards like in many less appealing languages :-) I also forgot to upvote you lol.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to use recursion:

```
def reverse(array)
  return array if array.size < 2
  reverse(array.drop(1)) + array.first(1)
end
```

We can make this tail-recursive using the standard accumulator trick:

```
def reverse(array, accum=[])
  return accum if array.empty?
  reverse(array.drop(1), array.first(1) + accum)
end
```

But of course, tail recursion is isomorphic to looping.

We could use a fold:

```
def reverse(array)
  array.reduce([]) {|accum, el| [el] + accum }
end
```

But fold is equivalent to a loop.

```
def reverse(array)
  array.each_with_object([]) {|el, accum| accum.unshift(el) }
end
```

Really, `each_with_object` is an iterator and it is the side-effectful cousin of fold, so there's actually *two* reasons why this is equivalent to a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another non-destructive approach:

```
arr = ["a", 1, "apple", 8, 90]

arr.size.times.with_object([]) { |_,a| a << arr.rotate!(-1).first }
  #=> [90, 8, "apple", 1, "a"]
arr
  #=> ["a", 1, "apple", 8, 90]
```

Another would the most uninteresting method imaginable:

```
(arr.size-1).downto(0).with_object([]) { |i,a| a << arr[i] }
  #=> [90, 8, "apple", 1, "a"]
arr
  #=> ["a", 1, "apple", 8, 90]
```

Answer (score 1):

Konsolebox is right. If they are asking for the method without loops, that simply means that you cannot use any kind of loop whether it is map, each, while, until or any even built in methods that use loops, like length, size and count etc.

Everything needs to be recursive:

```
def recursive_reversal(array)

  return array if array == [] # or array.empty?
  last_element = array.pop
  return [last_element, recursive_reversal(array)].flatten

end
```

Ruby uses recursion to flatten, so flatten will not entail any kind of loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse(array)
    array.values_at(*((array.size-1).downto 0))
end
```